# Going on a Budhist Pilgrimage and Want to Make it as Focused as Possible on the Buddha's Teachings

Tags: pilgrimage

I'm headed to India (and Lumbini in Nepal) in some months for a pilgrimage. This isn't a tourist trip. I want to make this trip as spiritually relevant as possible. Any sort of advice, tips, guidance as to important destinations within India would be most appreciated. This includes advice from Indian citizens regarding customs and culture, as I am a westerner. Thank you!

Comment: Wear conservatively and never go alone. Always go with a group. Carry enough water and other refreshments. Behave respectfully at religious places. Don't try to take photos in disrespectful ways. Don't get too familiar with strangers [Here is a list of places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddhist_pilgrimage_sites_in_India)

Comment: Most of this question would be more on-topic at [Travel.SE](https://travel.stackexchange.com) (but maybe too broad there too). Can you edit this question to focus more specifically on Buddhism?